# Docusign Webhook is not hitting into my application

Tags: webhooks, docusignapi

I created application and using e-signature using Docusign.
I want to get Envelop status updates using Docusign Webhook through eventNotification.

I hosted my website into public accessible environment also enabled ssl here is 
my webhook url - https://103.231.46.2:10167/api/webhook

As per the Docusign feature, when Envelop status gets changed then webhook try to post some data into webhook url but it's getting failed and I can see that failed post request at Docusign -> connect -> failure  tab. here is screen shot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCOeg.png)

I have check with with my network team, No firewall is blocking. and also tried to post some data using fiddler from other network it is working fine. then I am wondering, why Docusign webhook is unable to post data into my webhook url.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to access the URL https://103.231.46.2:10167/api/webhook

Looks like it is not publicly accessible.

Use a tool like [GeoPeeker](https://superuser.com/questions/848903/how-to-check-if-a-url-is-visible-from-the-public-internet) and make sure your URL is indeed publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0):

As CodingDawg suggested, it should either be publicly accessible or becasue of security concern you don't want it to be publicly accessible then you have to work with your Network/Firewall team to whitelist DocuSign IPs. You can find DocuSign IPs at

https://trust.docusign.com/en-us/trust-certifications/whitelist/